# Selecting last row for unique index ordered by column

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Objective

I have a list of payment records that contain `account_uuid`, `price`, `type` & `created_at`. I need to get a list of the latest payment record specific to each `account_uuid` where the `type` = `0`.

#### What I have tried

My first attempt was to `ORDER BY` on `created_at` to ensure the latest row was last, then to `GROUP BY` on `account_uuid`. The issue is that I would have to add both `account_uuid` and `created_at` to the `GROUP BY` expression which would include multiple records for the `account_uuid` as it will only group rows when both `account_uuid` and `created_at` are the same, which is never.

My second attempt was to `SELECT DISTINCT ON account_uuid`. This didn't work for the same reason above as it complains I must include my `ORDER BY` column in my `DISTINCT ON` expression which would yield the same result.

#### Sample Data

| account_uuid | price | type | created_at (↑) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa4dd27e-b72a-40fd-bdab-94810e585734 | 8.96 | 0 | 1649840899215 |
| 5c5625af-65e5-43d3-a39d-b896cd4d02a3 | 14.58 | 0 | 1649841117203 |
| aa4dd27e-b72a-40fd-bdab-94810e585734 | null | 2 | 1649843706217 |
| d8a106f9-dbf2-42f1-ac6b-a17e88700fab | 3.939 | 0 | 1650434747192 |
| aa4dd27e-b72a-40fd-bdab-94810e585734 | 14.58 | 0 | 1650438658596 |

#### Sample Result (Desired)

| account_uuid | price | type (=0) | created_at (↑) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5c5625af-65e5-43d3-a39d-b896cd4d02a3 | 14.58 | 0 | 1649841117203 |
| d8a106f9-dbf2-42f1-ac6b-a17e88700fab | 3.939 | 0 | 1650434747192 |
| aa4dd27e-b72a-40fd-bdab-94810e585734 | 14.58 | 0 | 1650438658596 |

#### Problem / Question

What I am trying to achieve is the sample result which you can see returns only the latest row for the `account_uuid` where `type` is `0` and `created_at` is ascending. Best case I would like to do it without any joins/subqueries but am happy for just getting it working.

#### Thank You

Comment: Why would not using SQL functionality of joins/sub-queries be best case?

Comment: @EdwardRadcliffe -- joins by themselves do not help

Comment: Understood, but specifying that the best case is to not use joins or sub-queries to solve a groupwise max problem is odd.

Comment: @EdwardRadcliffe -- yes I agree -- I actually did not see that requirement in the question till just now.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly have to be without joins/sub-queries. I am ideally looking for the most efficient query but if using a join or sub-query is the most efficient then that is perfectly fine. My question may not be asked in the best way. I understand this is where my knowledge of SQL is limited so looking for the best advise as well.

Comment: @Kal -- the most important thing for all of these queries to make them fast is to sure there is an index on account_uuid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: A simpler solution would be:

```
select distinct on (account_uuid) 
       max(created_at) 
       ,price
       ,type
       ,account_uuid
from tableName
where type = 0
group by price,type,account_uuid
```

You can achieve this in Postgres without using join/sub-queries by using a combination of `DISTINCT ON` and window functions. This assumes that you truly want the "latest row where type = 0" and not "If the latest row = 0".

```
select distinct on (account_uuid) 
       max(created_at) over (partition by account_uuid order by created_at desc)
       ,price
       ,type
       ,account_uuid
from tableName
where type = 0
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=22886f6ac1b235f031145c6922cb5d57)

Comment: why not use group by?

Comment: That would work too.

Comment: @kal you have an answer here. You should mark it as the answer.

Comment: This answer achieves the desired result of removing the unwanted rows but the resulting order is not correct

Comment: The queries produce the desired output based on your sample data, no?

Comment: Achieved the desired order using the following: `select * from (select distinct on (account_uuid) max(created_at) over (partition by account_uuid order by created_at desc)
       ,price
       ,type
       ,account_uuid
from tableName) as q order by max asc`

Answer (score 0):

You need select using ROW_NUMBER() in a sub query and then in the outer where statement you select RN = 1

There are many code examples of using ROW_NUMBER() if you search for it.